# Limit Content Editor Webpart

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to limit the content editor webpart, like you can with pagelayout rich text fields. For example I want to limit the use of inline styles, fonts, colors etc. Are there any alternatives to the content editor webpart, which can accomplish this?

Additional info:
The webpart is to be used on a publishing page and I do not want to limit the functionality of the publishing fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I ended up doing was to use the InputFormTextBox() like shown here: http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/inputformtextbox-control/

I used this technique and put it into a custom EditorPart for the webpart. The content is stored in a property of the webpart and edited in the webpart property pane.

[image: Simple User Interface for Text Web part]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply to hide corresponding buttons using ribbon customizations?

**Update:**

Sample code:

```
<CustomAction
 Id="RemoveButtons"
 Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
  <CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Styles" />
      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.Fonts" />
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
  </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

And here is what i've got after deployment:

[image: after customizations applied]

You should also specify `RegistrationType="ContentType"` and `RegistrationId="your-ContentTypeId-Here"` attributes in CustomAction element, if you want to apply this only for pages of your content type.

This should also work for sanboxed solutions.

Comment: No, but I do not want to hide it always. Just for content editor webpart.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have fixed number of pages, where the content editor webpart functionality must be cutted, or users could add a content editor to some new pages?
And also, what kind of pages do you use? Webpart pages? Wiki pages?

Comment: It is a publishing page with webparts.

Comment: Ok, so what you can try to do is to create a document content type, based on WebPart page, and then create a custom action for hiding the ribbon buttons you don't need to be shown, and bind this custom action to your new content type.

Comment: I've updated my answer with sample code. Please, try this.

Comment: That would work in most cases and I think its a very good answer. But in this case there is a requirement of publishing fields which should allow more, while the content editor should be more limited. For example publishing fields should allow fonts but content editor not.

Comment: If you'll bind the content type to a separate document library, and create a page there, and then add content editor webpart to that page, you will get the limits applied only to this page. So, your publishing fields will work without any limitations. Am I missing something?

Comment: The webpart and the publishing fields are to live on the same page, but they have different requirements. I want to tie down the webpart only, because it will have a very specific layout and style. I have updated my question to reflect this.